# How to create Website Tour with jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-plugins

I want to create a website tour for first-time login user to guide them through the website. I googled a lot but yet just can get one free website tour "plugin", which is this: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/12/21/website-tour/

However, the introduction given is too brief which I could not understand how to use it. I understand i need to have class for the element I want to go through, and declare this:

```
 var config = [
{
    "name"      : "tour_1",
    "bgcolor"   : "black",
    "color"     : "white",
    "position"  : "TL",
    "text"      : "Some text here",
    "time"      : 5000
},...
 ]
```

But I got no idea where should i declare this? inside the jquery.tour.js or just at normal View page? If it should be in normal View page, then how should i call the tour function??

Really hope can get some help here... Any other plugin recommendation is welcomed too.

Comment: I know their introduction is brief but have you thought about opening their demo page, viewing the source and pulling it apart to see how it all fits together?  Could also be a good starting point if no one else can help you.

Comment: hi, i had review the source and try..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I'd just create a well-edited video, as it's probably easier and friendlier to the user.

If you still wanted to go the seemingly fancy route, it's just a matter of having a start page for you tour, then highlighting items that the user should press with chained animations and descriptive popups to inform the user of what's going on (all easily done with a basic understanding of jQuery).  If you need to cross multiple pages, you'll most likely want to dynamically generate the touring javascript code based off of a query string, or post value that indicates the page is to be viewed in a tour mode.  Honestly, you could write hundreds, even thousands of lines of code to get this to work just the way you're probably imagining.

Most tours that I've seen (banks tend to use them a lot) are always video based.  It's easier to make, cleaner, and requires less interaction from the user (less room for error ;) )

Comment: Hi, i am thinking about issues where users sometime just "lazy" to click and view a video, not to mention about the buffering time. I came across lots of users like this...thats why I opt to a step-by-step tutorial...

Comment: Hi, I will be using step-by-step tooltip from qtip to do this. Just keep it a simple one. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use Guiders-JS https://github.com/jeff-optimizely/Guiders-JS.

It's a jquery plugin that allows you to create beautiful website feature tours that introduce your users to your site's functionality.

Here is an example of the plugin at work: http://jeffpickhardt.com/guiders/